# Decode text from WYSIWYG editor

Tags: decode, wysiwyg

I'm using TinyMCE as texteditor in my project, now I want people to write some text with newlines etc... , store it in my database, and show it on the website.

But the problem is the text gets saved with all the `<p>` for newlines in my database so when I show it on my website I got all the `<p>` in my text, is there any way to decode this to newlines?

Comment: TinyMCE replaces p with em, I think. Check about them. :) other method, in your savetodatabase  method replace all occurence of <p> with whatever you want and get rid of </p> after that.

Comment: Checks the options during init of tinymce such as: forced_root_block: false,
        force_br_newlines: true,
        force_p_newlines: false,
        apply_source_formatting: false,
        remove_linebreaks: false,
        convert_newlines_to_brs: true

Answer (score 0):

Which version of TinyMCE are you using? You should check the options during init of tinymce such as: 
  tinymce.init({

```
forced_root_block: false,
force_br_newlines: true,
force_p_newlines: false,
apply_source_formatting: false,
remove_linebreaks: false,
convert_newlines_to_brs: true
```

or you may directly replace on post process phase

```
editor.on('PostProcess', function(ed) {
                // perform clean
                ed.content = ed.content.replace(/(<p>&nbsp;<\/p>)/gi,'<br />');
            });
```